# Unable to view the jaxrs restful webservice

Tags: web-services, rest, java-ee-6, java-ee-5, java-ee-7

I am new to jaxrs , i followed this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Aec0KEDdzE tutorial for creating and deploying a restful web application and i also created a entity class and created a restful web service from a entity class and the when i deployed it from the server and when typed the path of the service i get page not found error from server and the web application is working contents from the web application can be viewed on the web page but unable to view the restful web service

```
package com.example.example;
import java.io.Serializable; 
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
 import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
 @javax.persistence.Entity
 @XmlRootElement
 public class Entity implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof Entity)) {
        return false;
    }
    Entity other = (Entity) object;
    if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private String firstName;

/**
 * Get the value of firstName
 *
 * @return the value of firstName
 */
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

/**
 * Set the value of firstName
 *
 * @param firstName new value of firstName
 */
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

private String lastName;

/**
 * Get the value of lastName
 *
 * @return the value of lastName
 */
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

/**
 * Set the value of lastName
 *
 * @param lastName new value of lastName
 */
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "com.example.example.Entity[ id=" + id + " ]";
}
```

}

Comment: Can you provide us with some code ? whay did you put in your web.xml ? do you have a JAX-RS Application activator, etc.

Comment: solved it and thanks anyway

Comment: I had type in the wrong url so only i got that error